# Setting JQuery selected does nothing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have the following layout

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Create Username</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">View Search Logs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Assign Values Table</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Edit Values Table</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Create Values Table</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <h2>Create Username</h2>

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <h2>View Search Logs</h2>

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <h2>Assign Values Table</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4">
        <h2>Edit Values Table</h2>

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-5">
        <h2>Create Values Table</h2>

    </div>
</div>
```

Each tab has a form in it, when the form is submitted and the page reloads I want the visible tab to still be the tab the user was last on (instead of it going back to the first).

Each form has a hidden field that contains the index of that tab. I then use the below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
     $("#tabs").tabs({ 
            selected: <?php echo (isset($_POST['selected_tab']) ? $_POST['selected_tab'] : 1)?> 
        });
   });

</script>
```

This results in showing the right thing e.g

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
     $("#tabs").tabs({ 
            selected: 2 
        });
   });

</script>
```

However the first tab is still the tab that is shown.

Comment: What plugin are you using there?

Comment: Seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/QdaMu/1/

Comment: If you are using jQuery UI, then the option is `active`, not `selected`: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/ (`selected` still seems to work as well though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     $("#tabs").tabs({ 
            selected: 2 
        });
```

Should be:

```
     $("#tabs").tabs({ 
            active: 2 
        });
```

Tabs uses `active` property and not `selected` property.
Also note that the index is base 0, so if you want to select the 2nd tab, your value needs to be `1`.

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to include `jquery-cookie.js` an use tabs like this:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    cookie: {
        expires: 1
    }
});
```

And this will automatically manage your last open tabs with cookie.

Comment: And why is cookie not `sureshot` method can you please explain?

Comment: Dunno where my earlier comment went, but there are cases where you need to control the index from server side, ALSO, cookies are not enabled everywhere.